# Sometimes no user is created at cognito via the Facebook login

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my react-native app I give the user the possibility to log in with a Facebook button.
For this purpose I use Amplify, which in Cognito should create a user in a user pool.
This works too, but for some reason it does not **always** work. 
I can't explain it either, because I don't use triggers that might contain a bug from my site.
The login does not work in about 40 percent of the cases.
The following actions lead to the error:

1. The user clicks the facebook button
2. The user will be forwarded to facebook
3. The user logs in to facebook
4. The user will be forwarded back to the react-native app.

Result: Now no user is created in the user pool and the following errors appear in the react-native app (via `Hub.listen("auth")`:

```
{"event":"signIn_failure","data":{},"message":"The OAuth response flow failed"}
console.js:35
{"event":"signIn_failure","data":{},"message":"The OAuth response flow failed"}
console.js:35
{"event":"cognitoHostedUI_failure","data":{},"message":"A failure occurred when returning to the Cognito Hosted UI"}
console.js:35
{"event":"cognitoHostedUI_failure","data":{},"message":"A failure occurred when returning to the Cognito Hosted UI"}
console.js:35
{"event":"customState_failure","data":{},"message":"A failure occurred when returning state"}
console.js:35
{"event":"customState_failure","data":{},"message":"A failure occurred when returning state"}
```

My app-client settings look like this:

[image: app-client setting]

Comment: I have this exact problem. Did you ever find out what was wrong?